# How to pass encrypted command to ffmpeg from Windows 10?

Tags: ffmpeg

While we pass commandline to **ffmpeg** and run it from *Windows*, others could see those commandline from taskmanager.
Sometimes the url and password are secret which to be hidden from others.
How to overcome this?

I don't know ffmpeg coders thought about it and done something for this already.
If I know C++ or relevant coding, I could add a custom decryption code block inside ffmpeg and use my encryption application to pass the encrypted command line.
I don't even know how to compile ffmpeg because its a nightmare even for professionals. (Why so complicated steps to simple compilation of an exe ?)

Usual command line:

```
ffmpeg -i MySource -codec:v h264_nvenc -s:v 1920x1080 -ac 2 -ar 48000 ... xyz ... -r 25 -f mpegts "udp://224.2.2.1:1234?pkt_size=1316"
```

My expected commad line line:

```
ffmpeg 8B8E108D96EBCA39415889F19E644D3EFA00D35941F383E28A5ED5  9D3A72CF8952C79AF2DA035949525C2D34ADDE5B9479217F5E739B0C515CE
20A1AE16120E22616
```

Comment: No, this isn't possible, and why would you bother with it anyway?  If someone wanted to see your parameters, they could just replace `ffmpeg` with their own copy.  If you're expecting to be able to hide something on a computer that someone has administrator/root access to, give up because it isn't possible.  Also, the rant about FFmpeg being hard to compile... you realize it's made of hundreds (thousands?) of sub-projects right?

Comment: My logic is 100% possible if some one know how to compile ffmpeg. And I need to hide the command lines from my competitors.

Comment: I suppose if you're going to make your super-secret-encrypted-parameter version of FFmpeg, you'll release the source code as well, right?  Because the GPL obligates you to do this.  And since then you can't hide your super-secret-encryption-key in the source, you'll have to put it somewhere else on the system that others can get at anyway, right?  You're so worried about hiding whatever you believe is secret about your FFmpeg parameters that you probably have forgotten that you're building your work off of the backs of others.

Comment: You are very correct. If I make the solution I will disclose it to the programmers as per GPL. Hope you know youtube video streaming needs a secret key. Youtube knows 99% of streaming code use the so called GPL based ffmpeg. Then what is the logic of secret key ? Secret is secret of individual. So lets not waste discussing this and find the solution. If you are serious to know I can send you some images where you can see others encrypted ffmpeg commandline. Thanks again...

Comment: It's trivial to intercept that key you send to YouTube *after* FFmpeg, so even if you go through all this trouble to try to encrypt what you send to FFmpeg, it doesn't protect you in any meaningful way.  If you're using regular RTMP, it shows up as plain-text in any packet capture.  For RTMPS, it isn't difficult to reconfigure your hosts file and set up a local certificate to man-in-the-middle the connection and get the relevant stream key.  And, all of this assumes that the target URL for YouTube's ingest isn't sitting around in an accessible config file anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice.
But I must explain other useful reason also.
Let's assume I buy a streaming server from you on rental.
You provide me a rtmp:// url to send and receive video stream.
I use that url on my ffmpeg commandline and push a live event (may be football match)

If I depute my servent to take care of the sreaming...
My servent will see the url from Windows Taskmanager commandline and 
may resell the paid url to my competitor because no need for any 3rd party sniffers.

Every one work for some money at least.
That's why I need to secure my commandline.